# How to mock the mongoDB client in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

We have written generic method to connect the MongoDB in golang. Now we want to write the unit testing to mock the DB call. So we need mock the mongo.client.
In Python, we have pymongo lib to mock db call. Similarly do we have any lib in golang?
Or
Do we have any other option to avoid the DB call for unit test implementation?

```
func RunQuery(collec string, filter bson.M, client *mongo.Client) (result []bson.M, err error) {
    collection := client.Database("TESTDB").Collection(collec)
    cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter)
}
```

I want to write a unit test for the method "getuserdetails".

```
func Test_getUserdetails(t *testing.T) {
  mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
  defer mt.Close()
  mt.Run("success", func(mt *mtest.T) {
    usercollection := mt.Coll
    getuserdetails(usercollection.Database().Client())
  })
}
```

Error:

Message: "no responses remaining"
Labels : NetworkError

Comment: You should clean up the question. But nevertheless this articles describe two solutions which might help you https://medium.com/@victor.neuret/mocking-the-official-mongo-golang-driver-5aad5b226a78

Comment: If you want to avoid making the calls to the database in your tests, why do you need a mocking library? Why not hide the database layer behind an abstraction (like an interface, or whatever Go has there) and then use a different implementation of that abstraction (like one that just uses memory for storage) in the tests?

Comment: Seems like you need to mock responses from the mocked collection: `func (t *T) AddMockResponses(responses ...bson.D)`